# Multiple "Add to cart" buttons with quantities specified

Tags: product, cart, price, quantity

Hi I would like to have three "Add to cart" buttons which add specified quantities for my products and remove the input field.

So rather than [qty input] [Add to card]

I'd like

[Add a single to cart]

[Add 6 to cart]

[Add 12 to cart]

Wondering on the best way to do this, I would also like to implement this on the product listing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these lines in list.phtml file for multiple add to cart buttons with specified qty.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product).'?qty=1' ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product).'?qty=6' ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>


<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product).'?qty=12' ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

please check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new parameter to getAddToCartUrl() function:

```
$additionalUrlParameters = array('qty' => 2);
$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product, $additionalUrlParameters);
```